# How to solve a surface integral

Tags: surface-integrals

How should I find the boundaries for the following surface $S:$

$S$ is the surface with equations $z = x^2+y^2 $ and $z\leq 1.$

I can find $x^2=1-y^2$ and take the square root to find the boundaries for $y,$ but how should I find the boundaries for $x?$

Thanks

Comment: Hint: draw a simple picture, and a coordinate change should suffice.

Comment: Should I change to polar coordinates and take p from 0 to 1 and theta from 0 to 2$\pi$?

Comment: ^Safe to say that's the best way

Comment: use symmetry, and reduce to first quadrant in $x,y$ or to $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$

Comment: Does $z\le1$ mean the surface is also made up of the disk $x^2+y^2=1$ (so that $S$ encloses some space), or does $S$ only consist of the paraboloid up to $z=1$?

Comment: Even if that's not the most efficient way, how should I find the boundaries for x without a coordinate change?

Comment: Since $x^2+y^2\geq0,$ you can assume $0\leq z \leq 1.$

Answer (score 1):

The trace of the paraboloid $$ z = x^2+y^2$$ in plane  $ z= 1$  projects onto the circle $$ x^2+y^2 =1 $$ in the $xy $ plane, and the portion of the paraboloid that lies below the plane $ z= 1 $ projects onto the region $ R $ that is enclosed by the circle. Thus, it follows from definition of surface area of surfaces of the form $ z = f(x,y)$ that $$ |S|  =\iint_{(R)}\sqrt{f'_{|x}(x,y)^2 + f'_{|y}(x,y)^2+1}dA = \iint_{(R)}\sqrt{ 4x^2 +4y^2 +1}dA. $$
The expresion $4x^2 +4y^2 +1 = 4(x^2+y^2)+1 $ in the integrand suggests that we evaluate the integral in polar coordinates. We substitute $ x =r\cos(\phi),\ \ y = r\sin(\phi)$ in the integrand, replace $dA = rdrd\phi $, and find the limits of integration by expressing the region $ R $ in polar coordinates. This yields $$ |S| = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{4r^2+1}rdrd\phi = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[ \frac{1}{12}(4r^2 +1)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{0}^{1}d\phi = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{12}(5\sqrt{5}-1)d\phi = \frac{1}{6}\pi(5\sqrt{5}-1).$$